# Write CSV with coordinates using R package sf

Tags: r, csv, spatial, r-sf

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to write a CSV of a point `sf` object (`sf` R package) that includes the coordinates.

You can use `st_write(input, "output.csv")` and it will write a CSV without coordinates. My hack for writing a file with coordinates is:

```
coords <- st_coordinates(input)
input_dat <- input %>% st_set_geometry(., NULL)
input_dat <- cbind(input_dat, coords)
```

But it seems there must be a simpler way.

As requested, here is the setup for the code above:

```
input <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, longitude = rnorm(10), latitude = rnorm(10))
input <- st_as_sf(input, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"))
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible?  Perhaps run `dput(input)` and copy paste it here.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 10):

I was sent to the solution by [Jakub Nowosad](https://nowosad.github.io/). He pointed me to [this github issue](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/284) which was solved by [Etienne B. Racine](https://github.com/etiennebr).

Apparently GDAL has a flag that allows you to include the coordinates. So:

```
st_write(input, "output.csv", layer_options = "GEOMETRY=AS_XY")
```

Answer (score 4):

You want a different treatment for POINT simple feature geometries from all other geometry types for something as basic as `as.data.frame`; I consider that feature creep. I think

```
cbind(as.data.frame(input), st_coordinates(input))
```

is easy enough, for this particular case.

`st_write` is meant to be your portal to all GDAL drivers and nothing more, it will do nothing with the data first, or manipulate GDAL settings by itself.

Comment: Thanks Edzer, agreed that the methods should be consistent but this is also probably an extremely common need. Your code is easier than what I wrote, but still not as easy as something like `st_write(input, "output.csv", coords = TRUE)` which I thought might exist. The `layer_options` argument works well for me though!

Answer (score 3):

There should be an easier way, I agree.  The `as.data.frame()` method for `sp` objects appends the coordinates and I feel like there should be one for `sf` objects too.  But for now, how about:

`input %>%
    cbind(., st_coordinates(.)) %>%
    st_set_geometry(NULL)`

Comment: Thanks Cole, I appreciate the effort on this but I think your solution is not really easier, it's essentially the same code as the question but repackaged a bit. I was hoping there was something I missing that would be like `st_write(input, "output.csv", coords = TRUE)`.

Comment: Agreed, I wish there was still a "non-hacky" way to append the coordinates.  Useful when you are using coordinates as an input to a model.